# Linking an external stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I had everything working within style tags, but as soon as I cut and pasted what was in the style tags to a .css and linked it, the style stopped working. the only thing I can think of is that the file path is wrong. My html file and the style sheet are in the same directory.

Here is how I linked it (this doesn't work):

```
<head>

    <title>Video Game Reviews</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">    
    
</head>
```

This does work though:

```
<head>

    <style>

          body { 
                background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255); /* this is the pink color */
                color: black;  /* color of font */
                font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; /* no tail font is more readable for small font */
                font-size:16px;
         }
   
    </style>

</head>
```

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in console?

Comment: no I do not see any

Comment: i know someone mentioned it below and it got removed, but if your css file is in the same folder as your html file, then just try: href="mystyle.css"

Answer (score 0):

that's the correct way to do it, however ensure that your file path matches. for your example above, the css file has to be in the same folder as the page you are working on and named correctly.

Comment: I have tried using the fully qualified path for the css file and that did not work, and I also tried moving the file around to different folders within the project and that still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

See that there are no HTML tags in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, are there any error regarding the `css` file? If yes, then try to use a full path for the `css` file

If no error in the console

- check the `Sources` in console
- navigate to external css link (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">`)
- right click
- open in new tab

Can the link be opened? If the link opened just fine without error and it display blank or not updated `css` file, then it's probably cached, try to change your link to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css?v=1.0">` (just add any query string that's never been used before to override the cached one)

Answer (score 0):

Once you move your CSS to an external file, you need to remove the HTML tags. CSS has it's own [formatting guide lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Organizing).

For example, for inline CSS (included in the HTML), you would do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Game Reviews</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
            color: black;
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body...
```

But once you move the CSS to an external file, the HTML tags are removed. For example:

**HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Game Reviews</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">  
</head>
<body...
```

**CSS file called *mystyle.css***

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

There a few other things to check for.

If you are referencing *mystyle.css* like this `./mystyle.css`, then the CSS file needs to be in the same folder or directory as the HTML file. That is what the `./` means.

If you store all your utility files (like CSS files) in a single location (something like `/rc`) you can use a full path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/rc/mystyle.css">
```

In this case, the `/` (no dot) means from the root directory of the website. But that is really a different question.

Answer (score -1):

Your said , your html & css are in the same directory, but ./mystyle.css makes html search for  a level up from the current directory.

Solution :-

Remove this(./)

Or

Move the css to a separate directory, say css.

So, now - css/mystyle.css

Comment: ./ = current directory.